# Replace Values in a customizable order spark scala

Tags: scala, loops, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to replace the null values in a dataframe with values where in each column I want the na s to be filled with the specific value of my choice for each column. The code I am using is as follows

```
val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(Seq(
  (10,null),
  (null,67),
  (14,null),
  (null,80)
)).toDF("V1","V2")

import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
def valreplace(data:DataFrame,valueList:list,columnList:list):DataFrame = {
    for (i <- columnList){
        val val = valueList(columnList.indexOf(i))
        val replaced = data.na.fill(val,Seq(column))
        val data = replaced
        }   
    return(data)
}
valueList = List(9,57)
columnList = List("V1","V2")
val na_rep = valreplace(data,valueList,columnList)
```

It should be such that na_rep is equal to

```
    +------+----+
    |    V1|  V2|
    +------+----+
    |    10|  57|
    |     9|  67|
    |    14|  57|
    |     9|  80|
    +------+----+
```

However I am unable to run this code. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use getOrElse().

Ex.

```
YourValue.getOrElse("NewValue")
```

Comment: It would be great if you can help me out in understanding where exactly I would incorporate this change